# Navigating asset based html files in webview on Nougat

Tags: android, webview

I am loading a HTML file from assets into a webview.

The html has links to other html asset files. Clicking the links works correctly on SDK < 24 but produces a `FileUriExposedException` error when clicking a link to a second html page on Nougat (SDK 24) devices.

Code to load the html from assets into a webview:

```
wbHelp.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", readAssetFileAsString("Index.html"), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

and readAssetFileAsString is:

```
private String readAssetFileAsString(String sourceHtmlLocation)
{
    InputStream is;
    try
    {
        is = getContext().getAssets().open(sourceHtmlLocation);
        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        return new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

The html can be very basic.
Index.html

```
<html><a href="Page2.html">Page 2</a></html>
```

Page2.html

```
<html><h1>Page 2</h1>
```

The full error log is:

```html
11-12 17:58:03.694 5831-5831/appname W/System.err: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///android_asset/Page2.html exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
11-12 17:58:03.694 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
11-12 17:58:03.694 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
11-12 17:58:03.694 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8933)
11-12 17:58:03.694 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8894)
11-12 17:58:03.694 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
11-12 17:58:03.694 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
11-12 17:58:03.694 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
11-12 17:58:03.694 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:77)
11-12 17:58:03.694 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:356)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.ResourcesContextWrapperFactory$WebViewContextWrapper.startActivity(ResourcesContextWrapperFactory.java:121)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient.sendBrowsingIntent(AwContentsClient.java:203)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient.shouldIgnoreNavigation(AwContentsClient.java:170)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(AwContentsClientBridge.java:256)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
11-12 17:58:03.695 5831-5831/appname W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
11-12 17:58:03.699 5831-5831/appname A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(236)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    --------- beginning of crash
11-12 17:58:03.856 5831-5831/appname W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
11-12 17:58:03.856 5831-5831/appname W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
11-12 17:58:03.856 5831-5831/appname W/google-breakpad: 1.0
11-12 17:58:03.856 5831-5831/appname W/google-breakpad: 72
11-12 17:58:03.856 5831-5831/appname W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
11-12 17:58:03.857 5831-5831/appname A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5831 (appname)
                                                
                                                [ 11-12 17:58:03.857   270:  270 W/         ]
                                                debuggerd: handling request: pid=5831 uid=10379 gid=10379 tid=5831
```

I've tried using some form of provider (such as in this answer: [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)) but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Why dont you use `"file:///android_asset/Index.html"` to let the file be loaded by the WebView?

Comment: I thought it was required to be able to auto load the images from assets but it looks like it works without it, however it still exhibits the same exception

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to overcome the exception by using the shouldOverrideUrlLoading, as suggested by @CommonsWare [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576567/on-clicking-the-hyperlink-in-webview-the-app-crashes-i-have-paced-all-the-html/40753538#40753538):

Tested on an emulator running Nougat:

```
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            Log.i("WebView", "Attempting to load URL: " + url);

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I do see this crash in my Dashboard, but I cannot reproduce this problem on the emulator (maybe depends on the browser associated with the Intent to trigger HTML links?)


However, with the proposed solution the links mailto: and tel: do not work. I can think of excluding this type of links from being loaded in the WebView (and also, to only use the shouldOverrideUrlLoading for APIs over 7.0).

Answer (score 6):

Also you can add this code in the onCreate method of you application or activity:

```
   StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
   StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

this lines makes your app ignore that exception.

And reading the documentation you will find that just using this code:

```
    WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    webView.setWebViewClient(client);
```

Will also work, because returning false you are asking for your webView to handle that operation.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)

Comment: In 2023, this method still works on Nougat. Thank you! I've been searching for this solution day and night. It's the only one that worked for me!